# how to return json value in [httpget] controller?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ajaxq

I want to return JSON value from controller to view when view load My controller code is bellow.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        List<selectdata_Result> tbl = new List<selectdata_Result>();
        tbl = context.selectdata("", "", "", "").ToList();
        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbl);
        return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my view is below

```
          $.ajax({
              url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Home")',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function (response) {
                  alert(response);
              },
              error: function (respons) {
                  alert("error");
              }
          })
```

I want to get my json value in alert(response).Give me some solution. when my page is load my json value is get

Comment: Remove `string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbl);` - its just `return Json(tbl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` which will serialize your collection (your currently serializing it twice). And then you use a loop in the success callback to iterate through the collection)

Comment: @StephenMuecke its work when i click on button goto [http] controller and return the json data correct. but in [httpget] same method its not work

Comment: Of course it will (but what do you mean `[http]` controller - do you mean a `[HttpPost]` method?) That makes no difference since your already have `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but it not work in httpget

Comment: Yes it will!  What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: no error jquery ajax is not run

Comment: What do you mean its not run? (and if its not executing, then it has nothing to do with the controller code anyway). Show the relevant information - how are you calling the ajax function

Answer (score 3):

With removing line string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbl); from controller, it will work. Here is the code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add()
{
    List<selectdata_Result> tbl = new List<selectdata_Result>();
    tbl = context.selectdata("", "", "", "").ToList();
    return Json(tbl , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And Ajax call as:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Home")',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (response) {
              alert(response.data);
          },
          error: function (respons) {
              alert("error");
          }
      })
```

Comment: its not workin only json value return my actual view not return

Comment: Omitting JsonConvert.SerializeObject fixed my problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
              url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Home")',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success: function (response) {
                  alert(response);
              },
              error: function (respons) {
                  alert("error");
              }
          })
```

Comment: How is that different from the code OP is already using (adding `dataType: 'JSON',` makes no difference)

Answer (score 0):

i would use

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Add()
    {
        List<selectdata_Result> tbl = new List<selectdata_Result>();
        tbl = context.selectdata("", "", "", "").ToList();
        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbl);
        var data = new { result = s }
        return Json(data);
    }
```

and

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'dom/controller/action',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function (response) {
              alert(response.data);
          },
          error: function (respons) {
              alert("error");
          }
      })
```